# How does C# remove duplicate instances of static data of constructed types?

Tags: c#, generics

Unlike Java, C# does not share static data among entire generic type, but per each constructed type (i.e. `Array<int>`, `Array<string>` and so on). Creating those instances does not seem a problem, but if I am not mistaken removing duplicate instances could be a problem (similar case **was** a problem for C++).

Thus my question -- how does C# remove duplicate instances of static data of constructed types?

Comment: I think it doesn't even create it. It is not hard to keep track of what static instances are already initialized and simply don't initialize it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not.

Static variables are lazily created/initialized on or before first use (practically, on first use, but if I remember correctly the standard doesn't *require* that). Since there is only one (unless threadlocal), the runtime only makes one.